# Creating a %change column in a long form data set

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to calculate a % change from one period to the next in a long data set. Here is an example of the format:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(Date=c(2001:2010),CompanyA=rnorm(10,0,1),CompanyB=rnorm(10,1,2),CompanyC=rnorm(10,-1,2))
longdf <- melt(df,id.vars="Date")
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
   Date variable       value
1  2001 CompanyA -1.20706575
2  2002 CompanyA  0.27742924
3  2003 CompanyA  1.08444118
4  2004 CompanyA -2.34569770
5  2005 CompanyA  0.42912469
6  2006 CompanyA  0.50605589
7  2007 CompanyA -0.57473996
8  2008 CompanyA -0.54663186
9  2009 CompanyA -0.56445200
10 2010 CompanyA -0.89003783
11 2001 CompanyB  0.04561460
12 2002 CompanyB -0.99677289
13 2003 CompanyB -0.55250779
14 2004 CompanyB  1.12891763
15 2005 CompanyB  2.91898812
16 2006 CompanyB  0.77942901
17 2007 CompanyB -0.02201901
18 2008 CompanyB -0.82239083
19 2009 CompanyB -0.67434336
20 2010 CompanyB  5.83167036
21 2001 CompanyC -0.73182356
22 2002 CompanyC -1.98137179
23 2003 CompanyC -1.88109574
24 2004 CompanyC -0.08082112
25 2005 CompanyC -2.38744049
26 2006 CompanyC -3.89640982
27 2007 CompanyC  0.14951144
28 2008 CompanyC -3.04731145
29 2009 CompanyC -1.03027660
30 2010 CompanyC -2.87189720
```

What I want is to add a 4th column which shows the % change in each company's score from one period to the next.

I can create this column by using the following code:

```
for (c in unique(longdf$variable)) {
  for (y in unique(longdf$Date)[-1]){
longdf$change[longdf$variable==c & longdf$Date==y] <- (longdf[longdf$variable==c & longdf$Date==y,"value"]-longdf[longdf$variable==c & longdf$Date==y-1,"value"])/abs(longdf[longdf$variable==c & longdf$Date==y-1,"value"])
  }
}
longdf
```

The resulting table would look like this:

```
   Date variable       value       change
1  2001 CompanyA -1.20706575           NA
2  2002 CompanyA  0.27742924   1.22983772
3  2003 CompanyA  1.08444118   2.90889283
4  2004 CompanyA -2.34569770  -3.16304743
5  2005 CompanyA  0.42912469   1.18294117
6  2006 CompanyA  0.50605589   0.17927471
7  2007 CompanyA -0.57473996  -2.13572427
8  2008 CompanyA -0.54663186   0.04890578
9  2009 CompanyA -0.56445200  -0.03259990
10 2010 CompanyA -0.89003783  -0.57681757
11 2001 CompanyB  0.04561460           NA
12 2002 CompanyB -0.99677289 -22.85205787
13 2003 CompanyB -0.55250779   0.44570343
14 2004 CompanyB  1.12891763   3.04326103
15 2005 CompanyB  2.91898812   1.58565198
16 2006 CompanyB  0.77942901  -0.73297972
17 2007 CompanyB -0.02201901  -1.02825018
18 2008 CompanyB -0.82239083 -36.34912573
19 2009 CompanyB -0.67434336   0.18002082
20 2010 CompanyB  5.83167036   9.64792433
21 2001 CompanyC -0.73182356           NA
22 2002 CompanyC -1.98137179  -1.70744467
23 2003 CompanyC -1.88109574   0.05060941
24 2004 CompanyC -0.08082112   0.95703509
25 2005 CompanyC -2.38744049 -28.53981030
26 2006 CompanyC -3.89640982  -0.63204479
27 2007 CompanyC  0.14951144   1.03837159
28 2008 CompanyC -3.04731145 -21.38179426
29 2009 CompanyC -1.03027660   0.66190637
30 2010 CompanyC -2.87189720  -1.78750114
```

The problem with the above code is it seems extremely inefficient. The data frame I'm working with is going to have millions of rows. Is there a more efficient way of creating a % change column for longform data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can use the `lag` function after grouping by the `variable` factor:

```
library(dplyr)

longdf %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(change = value / lag(value) - 1)

# Source: local data frame [30 x 4]
# Groups: variable [3]
# 
#     Date variable      value      change
#    (int)   (fctr)      (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1   2001 CompanyA -1.2070657          NA
# 2   2002 CompanyA  0.2774292 -1.22983772
# 3   2003 CompanyA  1.0844412  2.90889283
# 4   2004 CompanyA -2.3456977 -3.16304743
# 5   2005 CompanyA  0.4291247 -1.18294117
# 6   2006 CompanyA  0.5060559  0.17927471
# 7   2007 CompanyA -0.5747400 -2.13572427
# 8   2008 CompanyA -0.5466319 -0.04890578
# 9   2009 CompanyA -0.5644520  0.03259990
# 10  2010 CompanyA -0.8900378  0.57681757
# ..   ...      ...        ...         ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I found a function called Delt in the package "quantmod" that seems to do something similar. I'll give them both a try and see which is faster. Thanks again!